# Question on working out a pdf from a posterior distribution

Tags: probability, density-function, prior, posterior

Need help with part (a) of this exercise. The exact step I'm concerned about is calculating the pdf from the relationship given in the exercise. I will appreciate any explanations on how should I progress. The solution is clearly related to exponential distribution but I can't work the next. [image]

Comment: Hint for (a): what are properties of a pdf? particularly, one relating to integral of the pdf?

Comment: the integral of the pdf must equal 1. do you mean that?

Comment: yes...that should help you get the proportionality constant

Comment: proportionality constant meaning likelihood function?

Comment: based on the property that prior distribution is proportional to posterior times likelihood?

Comment: Would it be enough for part a to state that the pdf is the exponential pdf. theta * exp(-theta * x)??

Comment: well $\theta$ is the proportionality constant I was talking about. And perhaps the question wants you to *derive* it using the property of integral.

Comment: I understand how  is the proportionality constant. However I'm still stuck. if you could provide some details it would be so helpful

Comment: I just noticed that your pdf function has an $x^2$ instead of $x$...so it is not exponential distribution

Comment: so it would be chi-squared?

Comment: or normal distribution?